# How to check request for Mvc controller or Web api controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I integrate web api 2 request in mvc 5 project. How can I check request coming for mvc or web api controller?

Comment: in which part if the code, you want to identify ?

Comment: You will map this in MapConfig, and then the MVC will take care about this for you.

Comment: Log part : I want to log what kind of request. And for some part of project where some value stored in session. For api I want to take it from db. Is there any good to detect which kind of request it is ?

Answer (score 1):

The most correct way would be to create a class that inherits `ActionFilterAttribute` and override `OnActionExecuting` method. This can then be registered in the GlobalFilters in Global.asax.cs

Of course, this will only intercept requests that actually have a route.

Comment: Is not there more better solution than this ?